# Загрузка файла на сервер с прогрессом

Tags: c#

Как реализовать сабж в указанном окружении (portable class library) или какими воспользоваться объектами для этого?

Предполагаю следующую сигнатуру метода, который будет "дергать" вызывающий код и передавать в него некий хэндлер изменения прогресса на ЮИ:

```
Task UploadFile(byte[] file, IAsyncProgress progressHandler, CancellationToken token);
```

Вызов будет сводиться к:

```
await something.UploadFile(fileBytes, SomeHandler, someToken);
```

Вопрос состоит в том, чтобы понять как реализовать метод *UploadFile* и при помощи каких инструментов? (файл необходимо загружать методом PUT по протоколу HTTPS)

С "даунлоадом" у меня не возникло проблем, а вот "аплоад" сделать не получается из-за отсутствия найденных мною возможностей в portable библиотеке, которую я разрабатываю для:  WP7.5+, silverlight 4+, metro, .net 4+

ПС: с замечанием про недостаточность информации я согласен - предпологал, что те, кто сталкивались меня поймут, а вот "про погуглить" я все жду ответа..

Comment: Чем не подошел вариант "воспользоваться гуглом"?

Comment: Вроде не первый день ан ресурсе, а правильно спрашивать так и не научились.

Comment: @Flammable, Если бы я нашел в гугле ответ, то не пришел бы сюда. Ткните носом, если вы нашли!

Comment: @jimpanze, будьте так любезны и укажите мне на "неправильность" моего вопроса.

Comment: "Хочу построить дом на земле, чтобы у него окна были. Какими молотками пользоваться?" - абсолютно такой же вопрос, на который невозможно дань вразумительный ответ.  Постарайтесь более подробно описать ситуацию: какие файлы, на какой сервер, какой прогресс(с gui/без). и другие ценные факты.